# How to read path from input file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a txt file that has the path to xml files.now i want to read the path from the text file and print the number of tabs present in each xml file.how to do this?

here is what i have done

txt file with path

```
/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/searchplugins/bing.xml
/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/searchplugins/eBay.xml
/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/searchplugins/answers.xml
/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/searchplugins/wikipedia.xml
/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/blocklist.xml
```

code to count tabs in each file

code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
FILEPATH=/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/*.xml
for file in $FILEPATH; do
    tabs=$(tr -cd '\t' < $file  | wc -c);
    echo "$tabs tabs in file $file" >> /home/user/Desktop/output.txt
done
echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `/home/user/Desktop/files.txt` contains the list of xml files:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read file
do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
       tabs=$(tr -cd '\t' < "$file"  | wc -c);
       echo "$tabs tabs in file $file" >> "/home/user/Desktop/output.txt"
    fi
done < "/home/user/Desktop/files.txt"
echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo_O has provided an excellent answer.  However, there are chances that somehow, mostly due to text editor's preferences, your tabs were converted to 8 consecutive space.  If you would prefer to count them as tabs too then replace the "tabs" definition as:

```
tabs=$(cat test.xml | sed -e 's/ \{8\}/\t/g' | tr -cd '\t' | wc -c)
```

Full code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# original file names might contain spaces
# FILEPATH=/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/*.xml
# a better option would be
FIREFOX_DIR="/home/user/Desktop/softwares/firefox/"

while read file
do
    if [[ -f "$file" ]] 
    then
        tabs=$(cat test.xml | sed -e 's/ \{8\}/\t/g' | tr -cd '\t' | wc -c)
        echo "$tabs tabs in file $file" >> /home/user/Desktop/output.txt
    fi
done < $FIREFOX_DIR/*.xml

echo "Done!"
```

but this is applicable only if you prefer to count 8 consecutive spaces as tabs.